# Chicken plucker replacement gfci cord/plug

Tags: replacement

I have a 1.5 hp motor chicken plucker. The gfci plug that came on it has died and I can’t find another 13 amp gfci plug to replace it. Can a 15 amp gfci plug be used or am I going to kill the motor?

Answer (score 3):

Plug and device rating is just how much power they can safely handle.

It is the device, the chicken plucker, itself that will determine how much power it will take, under normal work.

This is why there are protection devices like breakers that will limit/trip if a device as a problem, like a short.

This is why you want a protection device/breaker very close or slightly above what the device should take.  Assuming the wires are made for that amount.

In North America 15 amps is usually the minimum circuit size, so finding a plug only rated for 13 amps will be hard.  They do use them in Europe, but the plugs will not fit in the US.

Most light bulbs use an amp or less, but they usually have a 15 amp plug or are on a 15 amp breaker.